# explicitly refer to a class without a namespace in C#

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

The code I'm working with has a class called **Environment** that is not in any namespace.  Unfortunately if I am in a class that imports the **System** namespace, there is no way to refer to the custom class called **Environment**.  I know this was an unfortunate choice and should be refactored, but is there any way I can explicitly refer to the conflicting class?

In C++ it seems the way to do this is by using **::**, and in Java there is something called **global::**  How do I do it in C#?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

C# also has a global (or unnamed) namespace - you can use `global::` to access your class:

```
global::Environment
```

See more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28VS.80%29.aspx). Also see the [`::`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) operator.

You can create an alias for it as well:

```
using myEnv = global::Environment;
using sysEnv = System.Environment;
```

Comment: @Oded your answer is a bit irrelevant. Question was: "but is there any way I can explicitly refer to the conflicting class"

Comment: @Andrey - The example shows exactly how to _explicitly_ refer to the `Environment` class that has no namespace.

Comment: Why didn't I try that... I knew about the Java solution :S

Comment: FYI you can also use a similar trick if you end up in the unfortunate situation of having two referenced DLLs which have the same type name in the same namespace. You say "extern alias FOO;" and then you can use "FOO::Blah.Bar" to mean "the Blah.Bar that appears in foo.dll". You just have to remember to say /r:FOO=foo.dll on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Should be `global::Environment` just like in Java

Comment: Java use folder structure for namespace. It will fill "package" name for you in any IDE. *C# still didn't resolve this in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

> The code I'm working with has a class called Environment  that is not in any namespace

You should absolutely change that. Or if it’s not your code, file a bug report and defer usage until the bug is fixed. Not using a namespace – that’s an absolute no-go.

(Notwithstanding the well-working solution posted by @Oded.)

Comment: can you justify this policy ?

Comment: @Proviste If that thread isn’t justification enough I won’t be able to change that. Namespaces avoid name clashes. That is all. It is a fixed policy in .NET, *never* to have a namespace-less class. Ever. The same counts for Java and packages. Namespaces only work if you use them. If you don’t use them – why support them at all?

Comment: thank you. i think it's a good way to easily share a class all over the app. I understand it's dirty. How would you get the same advantage with keeping a namespace ?

Comment: @Proviste “i think it's a good way to easily share a class all over the app” – you can do the same while using namespaces. What’s preventing you? Just to stress this again, using namespaces has *no* disadvantage. Not a single one.

Comment: "file a bug report and defer usage until the bug is fixed"
A bit harsh? Especially if you're working on something that a customer is waiting for. "Yeah, I know I told you it would be ready this week but I've stopped development for now because I don't like the decision that some other guy you know nothing about made. I'll just sit here twiddling my thumbs for now and wait for him to get back to me"

Comment: @noggin182 I didn’t say you should sit on your hands and not do anything. The code seemed to work just fine previously without using this ominous `Environment` class, I find it hard to believe that this suddenly changed now. All I said was: the class obviously wasn’t used (in this part of) the application before, and OP shouldn’t start to change that now – rather, they should wait until the code is fixed and *then* use it.