# Registering ASP user control defined in global namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, kentico

I'm trying to create a custom user control in ASP.NET WebForms and I need to reference another control defined in another assembly. The issue is that the code for that control does not feature a namespace definition, just a class definition.
I've read that in such circumstances the compiler adds the class to a default namespace (called the global namespace) and I'm not sure whether it's possible to reference that namespace in the `@Register` directive in my ASCX file and how.

Comment: this another control defined in another assembly, is it a server control or web user control? I mean is it extending any other control or just group of some controls?

Comment: It seems to be extending another user control and that one has a namespace. Could I use that namespace somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [explicitly refer to a class without a namespace in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767782/explicitly-refer-to-a-class-without-a-namespace-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @mason Unfortunately, that question does not explain how to reference a `Web User Control` that is defined globally inside another `Web User Control`. That is what I'm trying to find out: what to write inside the `Namespace` attribute of the @Register directive inside an .ascx file, if the control I'm referencing does not have any namespace.

Comment: You would register the control on the page life this `<%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="footer" Src="Controls/Footer.ascx" %>` and then in the `Footer.ascx.cs` file you'd add a property `public MyControlType MyControl {get {return MyControlId;}}` to expose it.

Comment: @mason I'm not sure I understand what `MyControlId` should stand for or which is the purpose of exposing it, with regards to the problem at hand. But besides that, and foremost, the control I'm referencing is located in another assembly, so I assumed that I would need the `Namespace` and `Assembly` annotations in the `@Register` declaration. Also, I assume that the `Src` attribute is only used for referencing controls in the same assembly.

Comment: MyControlId should be the ID of your user control, ex: `<scott:footer runat="server" id="MyControlId />`. If the control is in another assembly then you'll need to register by Namespace and Assembly instead of Src, but that means **you must put the control in a namespace**.

Comment: So I assume that what you're saying is that I can't reference a control from an external assembly if it is not placed in its own namespace?